# Filter structure with several parameters

Tags: json, go

I have an array of a struct and a maps with variable name and some filter values.
I want to filter my array with my maps.

Example [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ECvxU0S8Lj):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type cnts []cnt

type cnt struct {
    ID    int    `json:"Id"`
    Area  string `json:"Area"`
    State string `json:"State"`
    City  string `json:"City"`
}

func main() {
    mycnts := cnts{
        cnt{124, "Here", "South", "Home"},
        cnt{125, "Here", "West", "Home"},
        cnt{126, "", "South", "Home"},
        cnt{127, "Here", "West", "NY"}}
    // my maps with filter
    mapFilter := map[string]string{"Area": "Here", "City": "Home"}
    fmt.Println(mapFilter)

    mycntsFilter := make(cnts, 0)
    for _, val := range mycnts {
        // I want to select only row where the map filter it's ok
        mycntsFilter = append(mycntsFilter, val)
        fmt.Println(val, mycntsFilter)
   }
}
```

What is the best way to filter my data with dynamic filter (Represente here by a map of string)?

Comment: Some programming maybe? Stuff like ifs and fors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using golang package **reflect** in this particular case will be the best.

**reflect** will get you the fields of the struct and you can iterate
over them comparing the values with the corresponding filter value.

The example is **specific** to the struct that you provided, but you can easily modify it to **apply to all** structs, again using reflection.

Example: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Qfs6NdogEG)

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "reflect"
)

type cnts []cnt

type cnt struct {
        ID    int    `json:"Id"`
        Area  string `json:"Area"`
        State string `json:"State"`
        City  string `json:"City"`
}
// Filtering function
func filterItem(val *cnt, filter map[string]string) bool {
        item := reflect.ValueOf(val).Elem()
        itemType := item.Type()
        isValid := true
        // Iterate over the struct fileds
        for i := 0; i < item.NumField(); i++ {
                field := item.Field(i)
                filterValue, ok := filter[itemType.Field(i).Name]
                if ok {
                        // filter out  
                        if filterValue != field.Interface() {
                                isValid = false
                                break
                        }
                } 

        }

        return isValid
}

func main() {
        mycnts := cnts{
                cnt{124, "Here", "South", "Home"},
                cnt{125, "Here", "West", "Home"},
                cnt{126, "", "South", "Home"},
                cnt{127, "Here", "West", "NY"}}

        // my maps with filter
        mapFilter := map[string]string{"Area": "Here", "City": "Home"}
        fmt.Println(mapFilter)

        mycntsFilter := make(cnts, 0)
        for _, val := range mycnts {
               if filterItem(&val, mapFilter) {
                      mycntsFilter = append(mycntsFilter, val)
               }
        }
        fmt.Println(mycntsFilter)
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works well, I did not know the package Reflect.